# StartsWith Function is not working why? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in javascript, I was trying to build a filterable list, I am trying hard that why startsWith function is not working, I used keyup event and stores all li in the array (called as li) and iterating through the whole array of li and checking with the help of startsWith function that particular li startsWith val in the current input field or not, but it seems it is not working at all, please mention the reason why it is not working and how to rectify it ? I tried to test typeof both texts but they both are strings, therefore some debugging statement can be seen
Below is the HTML code(included bootstrap)

```js
 // this is the javascript code that I wrote
 var searchbar = document.querySelector('#usr')
            searchbar.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
                var val = searchbar.value.toUpperCase();
                // console.log(val)
                var lists = document.querySelector('.list-group')
                var li = lists.querySelectorAll('li.list-group-item')
                for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
                    let a = li[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase();
                    //console.log(`${a} ${a.length}`)
                    if (val.length <= a.length) {
                        //console.log(a.substring(0, val.length))
                        //console.log("aefaefael")
                        console.log(typeof (val))
                        console.log(typeof (a))
                        console.log(a.startsWith(val))
                        if (a.startsWith(val) === true) {
                            console.log("Hi")
                            li[i].style.display = ' ';
                        }
                        else {
                            li[i].style.display = 'none';
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Filtering Contacts</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/eb0a94b8cf.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body style="width: 40%; margin:5% 30%">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control fas" id="usr" placeholder="&#xf002; Search " />
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item active"> A</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Arab</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Aviral</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Aniket</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Alankar</li>
                <li class="list-group-item active"> B</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Brijesh</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Bhavesh</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Balram</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Bsnl</li>
                <li class="list-group-item active"> C</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Coonor</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Cremation</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Computer</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Create</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
         // js files from bootstrap
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: You have a space before each word in your list. You need to trim it before comparing `let a = li.textContent.trim().toUpperCase();` also `textContent` is more appropriate here than `innerHTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of `li` elements contains spaces. I'd advice to use `textContent` (so eventual html (see `li.active` in snippet) will not be a part of the comparison) and `trim` (to remove whitespace). Below is a clean snippet with simplified code to demonstrate. It uses [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) for the keyup event, by the way.

```js
document.addEventListener("keyup", search);

function search(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === "usr") {
    const value = evt.target.value.toLowerCase();
    document.querySelectorAll("ul.list-group li").forEach( li => 
      li.style.display = li.textContent.trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(value)
      //                    |           ^trim the value
      //                    ^use textContent
        ? "revert" : "none" );
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="usr" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item active"><b>A</b></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"> Arab</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"> Aviral</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"> Aniket</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"> Alankar</li>
    <li class="list-group-item active"><b>B</b></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"> Brijesh</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"> Bhavesh</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"> Balram</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"> Bsnl</li>
    <li class="list-group-item active"><b>C</b></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"> Coonor</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"> Cremation</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"> Computer</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"> Create</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have whitespace at the beginning of the `li` content:

```
<li class="list-group-item active"> A</li>
<li class="list-group-item"> Arab</li>
```

Use [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) on both `a` and `val`

```
var val = searchbar.value.toUpperCase().trim();
...
...
let a = li[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().trim();
```

Now, `startsWith()` will match because the whitespace is removed.

Alternatively, you could simply remove the whitespace in the HTML, but trimming is good practice, especially on the input value.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this doesn't work is that all the values start with a space. You can get rid of the whitespace using the trim() method.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth: here is my shortened version of it:

```js
var searchbar = document.querySelector('#usr');
searchbar.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
 let val=searchbar.value.toUpperCase(); 
 [...document.querySelector('ul.list-group').children].forEach(li=> 
  li.style.display=li.textContent.trim().toUpperCase().startsWith(val)?'':'none'
 );
});
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Filtering Contacts</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/eb0a94b8cf.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body style="width: 40%; margin:5% 30%">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control fas" id="usr" placeholder="&#xf002; Search " />
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item active"> A</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Arab</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Aviral</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Aniket</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Alankar</li>
                <li class="list-group-item active"> B</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Brijesh</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Bhavesh</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Balram</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Bsnl</li>
                <li class="list-group-item active"> C</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Coonor</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Cremation</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Computer</li>
                <li class="list-group-item"> Create</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
         // js files from bootstrap
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        
    </body>
    
    </html>
```